# How to validate column can be updated once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an agreement model and it has a `released_at` column. I want to validate that agreement is can be released **once.** How can I do that?

Controller:

```
 # GET /aggreements/1/release
 def release
   @agreement.update(released_at: Time.now.utc)

   if @agreement.save
     render json: {success: ["Agreement released."]}
   else
     render json: @agreement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
   end
 end
```

Model:

```
class Agreement < ApplicationRecord
  validate :released_agreement_cannot_be_released

  def released_agreement_cannot_be_released
    if released_at.present?
      errors.add(:released_at, "already released")
    end
  end
end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, here is the solution.

Controller:

```
 # GET /agreements/1/release
 def release
   @agreement.released_at = Time.now.utc

   if @agreement.save
     render json: {success: ["Agreement released."]}
   else
     render json: @agreement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
   end
 end
```

Model:

```
class Agreement < ApplicationRecord
  validate :released_agreement_cannot_be_released

  def released_agreement_cannot_be_released
    if released_at_was.present?
      errors.add(:released_at, "already released")
    end
  end
end
```